# Crawling Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, dynamic

I try to crawl this page of [crédit suisse](https://tas-creditsuisse.taleo.net/careersection/campus/moresearch.ftl?lang=fr-FR) (It's an exercice for me).

So I made this script, but I don't know how to get the data. I thought it is an iframe problem, but, it's not.
Then I thought it is an AngularJS website, but I think it's not.

So my code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://tas-creditsuisse.taleo.net/careersection/campus/moresearch.ftl?lang=fr-FR")

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='ftlhiddenframe']")

thepage = driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

webpage = ""
webpage = driver.page_source

webpage = "<body>"+webpage+"</body>"

import os
helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\Thie\\Desktop\\cs.html', 'w')
helloFile.write(webpage)
helloFile.close()

driver.close()
```

Somebody can give me the way to get this webpage?
Thanks a lot for your help.

---

The solution would be to make like the firefox inspector like on the picture below (select the TBody and save it in a file):

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what is wrong and what you want to get. Also are you getting an error, if yes - which?

Comment: I try to get all joboffer of this page, but I can't see the HTML text to get all joboffer link. Do you have a solution ? the solution would be to make the same as Firefox inspector

Comment: How to get the TBody, because it's hidden

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to switch to iframe. Delete this code:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='ftlhiddenframe']")
thepage = driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

---

Second, if I right understand you, you want to get all links to the jobs on the page. You can use this selector:

```
//span[@class = 'titlelink']/a
```

in code it will be something like this:

```
listOfAllJobLinksOnThePage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'titlelink']/a")
```

---

***PS*** remember, you will get only 25 links, if you want more you have to go to other pages and do the same

Comment: Thanks ;) it works ! Thanks ! You're right, it was not clear :) I need the link to go later on the job offer page and then get and crawl the job offer.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my help, you can upvote and/or accept my answer by clicking on the check button below upvote button